# How to specify a 'Or' conditional element specifier in Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

We can specify an "And" specifier in Watir, like

```
ie.link(:innertext=>"google",:href=>"http://www.google.com").click
```

Can we specify an "Or" specifier? like

```
ie.link(:innertext=>"google"||:href=>"http://www.google.com").click
```

Comment: I do not think `innertext` is a valid way of accessing element. Try `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if browser(:text => "google").exist?
  browser(:text => "google").click
elsif browser(:href => /google/).exist?
  browser(:href => /google/).click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that:

```
(ie.link(:innertext=>"google") || ie.link(:href=>"http://www.google.com")).click
```

Comment: it depends on what `link()` returns when there are not matching elements